# Save information in Graph Request response

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Good Day,

I would like to save the information in a `List<String>` the values that I get from `Graph Request` but when I return the `list`, its empty. Can someone help me why?

```
    private List<String> getFriends(AccessToken accessToken) {
     List<String> friendsName = new ArrayList<String>();
    GraphRequest requestt =
            new GraphRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    "/me/taggable_friends",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                      public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONArray arr;
                        try {
                          arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int l=0; l < arr.length(); l++) {
                                JSONObject oneByOne = arr.getJSONObject(l);
                                System.out.println(oneByOne.opt("name").toString());
                                friendsName.add(oneByOne.opt("name").toString()); 

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                    }
            );

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "name");
    requestt.setParameters(parameters);
    requestt.executeAsync();
     return friends;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the request asynchronously. It means that the request will not be executed immediately after `requestt.executeAsync();` but at some near point of future. That is why you are setting up the callback in the constructor. You should handle your `friendsList` in `onCompleted` callback instead of returning it in `getFriends`.

You can change the `getFriends` method to take `GraphRequest.Callback` as second parameter and make it return nothing. So it would look more or less like this:

```
public void getFriends(AccessToken token, GraphRequest.Callback callback) {
    GraphRequest requestt = new GraphRequest(token, "/me/taggable_friends",
                                             null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "name");
    requestt.setParameters(parameters);
    requestt.executeAsync();
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
getFriends(accessToken, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
              public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                List<String> friendsName = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                JSONArray arr;
                try {
                  arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int l=0; l < arr.length(); l++) {
                        JSONObject oneByOne = arr.getJSONObject(l);
                        System.out.println(oneByOne.opt("name").toString());
                        friendsName.add(oneByOne.opt("name").toString()); 
                    }
                    //CONSUME YOUR FRIENDS LIST HERE
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
    );
```

It would be a good idea to rename your `getFriends` method to `getFriendsAsync`

The better idea would be to create your own, more specified callback.

```
public interface FacebookFriendsCallback {
    void onFriendsReceived(List<String> friendsNames);
}
```

And use it like that:

```
public void getFriends(AccessToken token, FacebookFriendsCallback callback) {
    List<String> friendsName = new ArrayList<String>();
    GraphRequest requestt =
        new GraphRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/me/taggable_friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
              public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                JSONArray arr;
                try {
                  arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int l=0; l < arr.length(); l++) {
                        JSONObject oneByOne = arr.getJSONObject(l);
                        System.out.println(oneByOne.opt("name").toString());
                        friendsName.add(oneByOne.opt("name").toString()); 

                    }
                    callback.onFriendsReceived(friendsName);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
    );
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "name");
    requestt.setParameters(parameters);
    requestt.executeAsync();
}
```

And then call `getFriends` method:

```
getFriends(accessToken, new FacebookFriendsCallback() {
    public void onFriendsReceived(List<String> friendsNames) {
        //consume list here
    }
}
```

NOTE: this is not a tested, ready to copy-paste code. Rather the idea for your own implementation. Also some error handling would be needed.

Comment: if I handle the friendList inside onCompleted. How can I brought it outside the getFriends method? Cause I will use the list in the method calling the getFriends method. Thanks

Comment: You can change the `getFriends` method to take `GraphRequest.Callback` as a parameter and pass it to the request. See my updated answer.